# Obter valor de radio button via jQuery e setar em PHP

Tags: php, jquery

Tenho que capturar um evento de `click` em um *radio button* e passar o seu valor em uma variável PHP para poder fazer um calculo de valores, não tive muito sucesso, segue o meu código.

```
function Tipo_Frete() {
    var frete = $("input[name='tipo_frete']:checked").val();          
    if (frete == "PAC") {
      frete = 'pac'
    }else if(frete == 'SEDEX'){
      frete = 'sedex'
    }        
}  

<?php $frete = "<script>document.write(frete)</script>";
```

O que eu preciso mesmo agora é que essa variável seja acessada ainda na *view*, sem precisar passar pelo *controller*. Preciso que uma variável PHP receba o valor do `button` marcado, para que no PHP eu possa fazer o cálculo. Como fazer tudo isto  acontecer de forma dinamica, sem precisar submeter isto junto com o formulário, e tratar tudo na *view*?

Comment: Você precisa passar via post ou get para o php, desta forma, a variavel "frete" não existe no contexto do servidor. Use ajax para passar a variavel "frete"  para o php e capture usando a global $_POST ou $_GET, dependendo de como for feita a requisição no ajax.

Comment: Pode usar ajax ou passar na url como falou o @DiegoFelipe ou ainda passar em um campo hidden via submit do form.

Comment: Obrigado pessoal, mais o que eu preciso mesmo agora é que essa variavel seja acessada ainda na view, sem precisar passar pelo controller, preciso que uma variavel php receba o valor do button marcado, para que no php eu possa fazer o calculo, tudo isto precisa acontecer de forma dinamica, entendem, não posso submeter isto junto com o formulário, preciso tratar tudo na view.

Comment: Então a solução é usar ajax, assim, você faz uma requisição apenas quando o radio button for alterado.

Comment: ok, muito obrigado a todos, conseguimos por aqui, usamos jquery e deu certo, valeu.

Comment: Se puder compartilhar sua solução, vai ajudar outros com o mesmo problema. É só postar uma resposta abaixo. Valeu!

Answer (score 1):

A solução é usando AJAX

no seu `.js` (usando jquery)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   //gatilho para executar o ajax no click do radio (da escolha PAC ou SEDEX)
   $("input[name='tipo_frete']").click(function(){
      $.post('/script_que_calcula.php',{
         //fazendo dessa forma abaixo o seletor pega o valor do radio    selecionado e atribui a variavel com o valor correto
         frete: $("input[name='tipo_frete']").val() == "SEDEX" ? "sedex" : "pac"
      },function(data){
          /*aqui recebemos um objeto json com o valor 
          do frete no atributo 'valor' é evidente que
          a lógica para esse calculo deverá estar em 
          seu script e atualizamos o elemento na 
          view sem atualizar a página (refresh)*/
          $("#valor_frete").val(data.valor);
      },"json");
   });
});
```

abaixo vamos imaginar o seu `script_que_calcula.php`

```
<?php
     $array = array();

     //abaixo está como deveria ser feito o retorno para a
     //requisicao ajax... é claro que deverá conter sua lógica de negócio
     if($_POST['frete']=="sedex"){
        $array("valor" => "valor do sedex");
     }
     else{
        $array("valor" => "valor do pac")
     }

     /*aqui está o retorno sendo 'encodado' 
     para json assim sendo possivel usar no ajax*/
     echo json_encode($array);
```

é um exemplo bastante simples do uso de ajax, é o uso ideial para chegar a solução desejada